# stop execution of function from express route

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to stop the execution of a function when the connection is lost in a express route, I have something like this.

```
app.post('routeName',function (req,res,next)=>{
   req.on('close',()=>{
      //do something to stop function
   });

 module.myFunction(req, (err,result)=>{
   //do something with the result
})
})
```

myFunction is does some mongo queries that can take a while (mostly for server side filtering large sets of data) but sometimes the function is call again if a new filter is set, in this case I want to stop the work that myFunction is doing. I can call res.end(), or return res.end() or something like that  in the onClose listener but whatever work is being done in myFunction still keeps going. I trying adding the req.on('close') where the function is but that event does not get trigger once the req object is passed into myFunction. any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: There is no way to cancel/terminate function execution since it started. If you have long-running async job, the only option is to wait untill it ends.

Answer (score 0):

Promisify the end event:

```
 const ended = new Promise((_, rej) => req.on('close', rej));
```

Then pass that down to all your functions, and whenever you do something async, replace:

```
 await sth();
```

with:

```
 await Promise.race(ended, sth());
```

Now `try {} catch` the most outer call, and you are done :)